# Slideshow - change arrows and scroll down a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have auto-moving images as a slideshow.

Here's my code in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/Krzysiek_39/pen/poNLbgx

Here is the same slideshow:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/mobile-json-carousel/

In the above website with this slideshow, I don't like the left arrow (including the blue circular background) and the right arrow (including the red circular background).
On my code, instead of the left arrow, I have "previous" and instead of the right arrow I have "next".
If the mouse scroll is normally scrolled up on my code, the "previous" and "next" buttons work properly.
If I scroll the mouse down a bit on my code, there are 6 dots at the bottom in the middle of the pictures. After pressing a particular dot, you can go, for example, from image 2 to image 5, etc. etc. - this also works properly.

Unfortunately, if I scroll the mouse more down (no visible blue background at the top), the "previous" and "next" buttons do not work. Additionally, these dots at the bottom also don't work when pressed.

Here is another slideshow with normal arrows:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Infinite-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-LoopSlider/

I would like to have two fixes in my code:

1. Can I put these normal arrows (from another slideshow) in my code in place of the ones I don't like?
2. Can I make the normal arrows and the dots at the bottom work properly if I scroll the mouse further down?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

```
<div class="header-container">

    <div class="header">
    
        <div class="text">
            <a class="refresh" title="A website refresh">Website</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="menu-container">
    
        <div class="menu">
            <a>MENU</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="content">

    <div class="box">
    
        <div class="slider_wrapper">
        
            <div class="slider">
            
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?art" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 1</span></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?action" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 2</span></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?war" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 3</span></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?crime" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 4</span></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?drama" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 5</span></a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="slider_img_wrapper">
                    <a href="#"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?sci-fi" alt=""><span class="caption">Caption for slide 6</span></a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="slider_objects">
            
                <div class="slider_btn prev_btn">previous</div>
                <div class="slider_btn next_btn">next</div>
                
                <ul class="slider_list_wrapper">
                    <li class="slider_list active_slide"></li>
                    <li class="slider_list"></li>
                    <li class="slider_list"></li>
                    <li class="slider_list"></li>
                    <li class="slider_list"></li>
                    <li class="slider_list"></li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll, your `menu-container` element becomes `.sticky`, and then it covers the entire height of the viewport, because it has the following css:

```
.menu-container
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 0;   /*You must remove this*/
    width: 90%;
}
.sticky
{
    width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

So it covers the previous/next buttons among other things, preventing to click those. If you remove `bottom: 0` from your CSS, then it should occupy just the required height and gone is the problem.

**Edit** I just realized I hadn't answered question 2.

For that, replace the CSS in your CodePen for `.prev_btn` and `.next_btn` with the following:

```
.slider_objects .prev_btn
{
    background: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/467/467274.svg?token=exp=1620309354~hmac=54b31aaae04ca8b410094009035d2e75') center no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: -1000px; 
    left: 50px;
}

.slider_objects .next_btn
{
    background: url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/467/467282.svg?token=exp=1620309031~hmac=dbdabb598f775825811da1ebe357f558') center no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: -1000px; 
    right: 50px;
}
```

You'll still have to chose your arrow icons and manage the hover effects, but the idea's here

Comment: @webmaster40 Just tried again on Chrome and Firefox, and it works. It sure doesn't make anything worse in the codepen you linked: https://codepen.io/Krzysiek_39/pen/poNLbgx . Just remove the `bottom: 0;` line